# Syntax of printf in C

Tags: c, printf, implicit-conversion, string-literals

I am a beginner in C and I mostly used the following two formats  of printf

```
#include <stdio.h>

//Compiler version gcc  6.3.0

int main()
{
  int c=5;
  printf("Hello, World!\n");
  printf("%d",c);
  return 0;
}
```

But recently I found out that there is one more way to write printf i.e. **printf(string pointer)**, how this format is so different from the other two,there are no quotes and why there is string , the question can be a silly one but try to understand that I am just a beginner.

Comment: Actually, it's exactly the same as you use with `printf("Hello, World!\n")`. And also note that it's not really different forms of the `printf` function, it's just that in some you pass extra arguments and to some you don't.

Comment: Also note (and this is rather important): You should *never* pass a variable as the format string. If you use `printf` with user-input, what's to stop the user from providing format specifiers in the input, causing `print` to attempt to use arguments that doesn't actually exist. If you want to print a user-input string, then either use `printf("%s\n", user_input_string)` or `puts(user_input_string)`.

Comment: there's only a single definition of `printf`: `int printf(const char *restrict format, ...);`. Just read [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)

Comment: Please note that `printf` is a [variadic function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/variadic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it looks different in your editor, it's actually the same.

When you write

```
printf("Hello, World!\n");
```

in your editor, your compiler in principle change it to

```
char* hidden_unnamed_string = "Hello, World!\n";
printf(hidden_unnamed_string);
```

The string "Hello, World!\n" is called a string literal. The compiler will (automatically) place it somewhere in memory and then call `printf` with that memory address.

Here is an example from godbolt.org

[image]

On the left side you have the C program as it looks in your editor. To the right you have the compiled program.

Notice how the string is located outside the code block and labeled with LC0. Then inside the code block LC0 is loaded into edi (i.e. the address of/pointer to the string is loaded into edi) just before calling the printing function.

Also notice that the compiler decided to use `puts` instead of `printf`. Further notice that the string is stored **without** the `\n`. The reason is that `puts` unlike `printf` automatically adds a `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

For starters instead of this call of printf

```
printf("Hello, World!\n");
```

you could use a call of puts like

```
puts( "Hello, World!" );
```

The string literal `"Hello, World!\n"` internally is represented as a character array like

```
char string_literal[] = 
{ 
    'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ',', ' ', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '!', '\n', '\0' 
};
```

Arrays used in expressions are implicitly converted (with rare exceptions) to pointers to their first elements.

So in this call

```
printf("Hello, World!\n");
```

the character array used as an argument of the function call is converted to pointer of the type `char *` to its first element `'H'`. You can imagine that the following way

```
printf( &"Hello, World!\n"[0] );
```

Thus the function deals with a pointer of the type `char *`.  You could do the same by introducing an intermediate variable

```
char *s = "Hello, World!\n";
printf( s );
```

or

```
char *s = "Hello, World!\n";
printf( "%s", s );
```

or

```
char *s = "Hello, World!";
printf( "%s\n", s );
```

or

```
char *s = "Hello, World!";
puts( s );
```